# Is it Possible to get itunes like xml/json data from android market for each App

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, api, google-play

Itunes provide URL or all apps in App-store like to get details in **JSON/XML Format**

```
http://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=[appid]
```

There is no any API for android market i have got online. i tried to get details from these html pages using java script by fetching android market query

```
https://market.android.com/details?id=com.[companyname].[app name]
```

but it is not getting fetch all the relevant data as iTunes. Is there any way i can fetch all data from android market app page html code or any API available for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be it's help to you http://code.google.com/p/android-market-api/
By the way, last rumors, Google has renamed Android Market to Google Play.

Comment: Is it possible to fetch the same thing using unix shell script and without using and webbased language(like php used here)

Answer (score 0):

To expand on devzorg's answer, - yes http://code.google.com/p/android-market-api/ will give you the application data you seek. And no - the format isn't (quite) valid JSON, although it is close afaik. The example snippet below (from an AppsResponse using the Android Market Library) won't pass JSON validation on jsonlint.com until you add quotes to all the variables and a set of external parens.

app {
  id: "v2:com.geodesic.munduTV:1:30818"
  title: "Mundu TV- Mobile TV, Live TV"
  appType: APPLICATION
  creator: "Geodesic"
  version: "3.4.4"
  rating: "3.6129606"
  ratingsCount: 2253
..
}

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Google Play (previously known as Android Market) does not expose an API like the Apple App Store, officially named [iTunes Search API](https://affiliate.itunes.apple.com/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api/).

To get the data you need, you could develop your own HTML crawler, parse the page and extract the app meta-data you need. This topic has been covered in other questions, for instance [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17002181/crawling-the-google-play-store?rq=1).

If you don't want to implement all that by yourself, you could use a third-party service to access Android apps meta-data through a JSON-based API.

For instance, [42matters.com](https://42matters.com?utm_source=stackoverflow.com&utm_medium=Referral&utm_campaign=9633396) (the company I work for) offers an API for both Android and iOS, here more details:

[https://42matters.com/app-market-data](https://42matters.com/app-market-data?utm_source=stackoverflow.com&utm_medium=Referral&utm_campaign=9633396)

The endpoints range from "lookup" (to get one app's meta-data, probably what you need) to "search", but we also expose "rank history" and other stats from the leading app stores. We have extensive documentation for all supported features, you find them in the left panel: [https://42matters.com/docs/overview](https://42matters.com/docs/overview?utm_source=stackoverflow.com&utm_medium=Referral&utm_campaign=9633396)

I hope this helps, otherwise feel free to get in touch with me. I know this industry quite well and can point you in the right direction.

Regards,

Andrea